# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\int_{0}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx) \not= \int_0^\infty f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

There is a sequence of functions, $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\ldots$, whose domain is $[0, \infty)$, such that $$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x \in [0, n) \\
      \frac{-1}{n}x+1+\frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x \in [n, n+1) \\
      0 & \text{if } x \in [n+1, \infty) \\
   \end{cases}$$

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\int_{0}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx) \not= \int_0^\infty f(x)dx$. So they should not be the same as the integral of the limit. As to how I can solve it, I tried but is not successful. Actually, I try to convert this is improper integral, to normal integral. I am stuck though.

Comment: Note that $\int_{A\cup B\cup C} g(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_A g(x)\,\mathrm dx + \int_Bg(x)\,\mathrm dx + \int_Cg(x)\,\mathrm dx$ for disjoint sets $A = [0,n)$, $B = [n,n+1)$, and $C = [n+1,\infty)$. Furthermore, $\int_a^b \lambda x\,\mathrm dx = \frac\lambda 2b^2 - \frac\lambda 2a^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\equiv 0 $$ so $$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=0 $$ on the other hand, $$I_n=\int_0^\infty f_n(x)dx =\int_0^n f_ndx+\int_n^{n+1}f_ndx+\int_{n+1}^\infty f_ndx$$
so $$I_n= \int_0^n \frac{1}{n}  dx-\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}x-1-\frac{1}{n}  dx+\int_{n+1}^\infty  0dx$$ then
$$ I_n = 1+\frac{1}{2n}$$ so we see taking $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=1\neq 0$. And the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

The functions get shorter and shorter as $n$ increases, and each slants down to zero between $n$ and $n+1$. The integrals of the individual functions are all, one plus the area of the small triangle, which gets smaller as $n$ increases.  So the limit of the integrals is $1$.  The integral of the limit, however is different, because the limit of the sequence of functions is the zero function, which integrates to zero.